# Scala: filtering out tuples where specific properties are None

Tags: scala, filter

I have a `Summary` case class:

```
case class Summary(
  title: String,
  desc: String,
  image: Option[String],
  path: String,
  timestamp: Int
)
```

I attempt to retrieve a Summary for each ID I have:

```
val rawSummaryList = nids.map {
   _ match {
     case Some(id) => (id, Node.nodeSumByNid(id))
     case None => (-1, None)
   }
}
```

This returns a value of type `List[(Int, Option[drupalslick.data.Summary])]` and each Summary may, or may not, contain an image.

How do I:

1. Drop `(Int, Option[Summary])` pairs where either `Summary` or `Summary.image` is None?
2. Convert `(Int, Option[Summary])` to `(Int, Summary)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  val rawSummaryList: List[(Int, Option[Summary])] = ???

  val filtered: List[(Int, Summary)] = rawSummaryList collect {
    case (id, Some(summary)) if summary.image.isDefined => (id, summary) 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  This one seems a little more legible to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collect` function, which is a combination of `map` and `filter`, e.g:

```
val list: List[(Int, Option[drupalslick.data.Summary])] = ???
list.collect { case (int, Some(smr @ Summary(_, _, Some(_), _, _)) => (int, smr) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for-comprehensions:

```
  val rawSummaryList: List[(Int, Summary)] = for {
    Some(id) <- nids
    summary <- Node.nodeSumByNid(id)
    image <- summary.image
  } yield (id,summary)
```